# Access changed base class instance attribute in derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, instance-variables

I have trouble understanding the logic of instance variables in inheritance. 
This is my (simplified) code with comments explaining how I understand its behaviour:

```
class Main(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = Parent()  # self.parameter = []
        self.c = Child()  # self.parameter = []

    def run(self):
        self.p.setting()  # assigning value to self.parameter
        self.c.getting()


class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.parameter = []

    def setting(self):
        self.parameter = [1, 2, 3]


class Child(Parent):
    # not redefining __init__, so Parent __init__ is called

    def getting(self):
        # value was assigned to self.parameter in setting method,
        # called before getting
        print self.parameter


Main().run()
```

`getting` prints `[]`, instead of `[1, 2, 3]` which I expected. Why is it so? Since `Child` shares `__init__` with `Parent`, at the beginning `self.parameter = []` for both but why is it still `[]` when it was assigned a value long after `Child().__init__` was called? What should I do to get changed `self.parameter` value in `getting`?

Comment: Python is not Java; not everything has to be a class. Get rid of `Main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go through execution of your code.

1. `main` instance is created with `Main()`.

At this moment we have `main.p = []` and `main.s = []`, as defined in `Main.__init__`

2. `main.run()` is called, and it calls `main.p.setting()` and `main.c.getting()`

So now, `main.p.setting()` changes the `parameter` value of `main.p` to `[1,2,3]`, and `main.c.setting()` just prints its own `parameter` value, which is still `[]`, as it was never modified.

If you want to modify `main.c.parameter` value, simply call `main.c.setting()`

```
main = Main()
main.c.setting()
main.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not inheriting from anything here in `Main`, you're adding member variables.  You're expressing a "has a" relationship, not an "is a".

To inherit, define `Main` as such:

```
class Main(Child):

    def run(self):
        self.setting()
        self.getting()
```

With your current code, you could inspect `main_instance.p.parameter` after calling `main_instance.run()` and see that `[1, 2, 3]` is returned.